# Enable the easy review close queue filtering interface

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queue

We are almost reaching the 1k items in the close queue (we are second, only behind Stack Overflow), so I think we should make any attempt to make folks review stuff and for that reason I ask to enable [this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231856/213575) which would promote the use of filters to review close reasons.

I'm sure this was enabled at some point of time in AU and later disabled. BTW, our queue is mostly composed of duplicates which I believe is something worrisome.

Comment: I'd like that too. It was enabled at one point, and I used it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done:

[image: filtered review UI]

[image: filter link on tag page]

Note that only tags with at least 20 questions currently in review will show an indicator on the tag page itself.

Enjoy...

Comment: Awesome, thanks!